# No in-text citation and bibliography appearing

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using `natbib`, and all in-text citations appearing as "?" and no references page at all.
MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\begin{document}

\bibliography{Refs}

\end{document}
```

My bib document is called "Refs.bib", and an example of one of the references in there:

```
@article{flu18,
title = {The alliance in adult psychotherapy: A meta-analytic synthesis},
journal = {Psychotherapy},
volume = {55},
number = {4},
pages = {316-340},
year = {2018},
issn = {},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1037/pst0000172},
author = {Fluckiger, C., Del, A. C., Wampold, B. E., & Horvath, A. O.}}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  To get the bibliography entries into your output, you have to process first with latex, then with bibtex, and then twice more with latex.  You also need a `\bibliographystyle` specification.

Comment: I am using \bibliographystyle{siamplain}, and the issue persists